# How can I find the models from content type generated at using the admin Panel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, content-management-system, orchardcms

When I create a custom content type using the admin panel (as explained at http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-custom-content-types), how can I find the Models for this content type in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any. You created it dynamically. This doesn't generate code, but metadata that gets stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks @Bertrand for the answer. But this answer made me think:

If I use the admin panel to create a content type, 
it seems that I can't reuse the content type I just created and modify it on code, because it is created dynamically.

It seems that if I need to create a content type and have more control over it (for example it's model), 
I need to start creating it manually on code.

Comment: You can still modify it through code. There is actually little difference between admin-created and code-created. What I was pointing out is that it doesn't generate code, just metadata. But look into any migration in any module and you'll see content types created or modified from code.